# Price increases after every 10 liters

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, calculation

So I'm currently at my internship and I want to make something for the website of the company.
Basically I want to increase the price by X every 10 liters.
I am currently used to PHP, HTML, CSS, JS, MYSQL, WordPress.

So when someone enters the following in the form:

Length: **2**(cm);
Width: **4**(cm);
Height: **10**(cm);
Weight: **15**(cm);

Which is equal to:

2 * 4 * 10 == 80 cm3
80 / 1000 = 0.08 liters

So now comes the hard part.
The Formula..

Currently I use the following:

```
define("DEFAULT_PRICE", 25);

$length = $width = $height = $weight = $total= "";

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
    var_dump($_POST);

    $length = $_POST['length'];
    $width = $_POST['width'];
    $height = $_POST['height'];
    $weight = $_POST['weight'];

    $content = $length * $width * $height;
    $contentL = $content / 1000;

    $total = number_format(DEFAULT_PRICE + ($contentL * $weight), 2);

}
```

Every time when I change one of the inputs 1 cm lower than it was set to, the price instantly decreases.
My goal here is to have the price increase/decrease whenever its 10 liters higher.

So everything between 0 - 10 liters (decimals included) is for Example €27.50. But everthing from 10.01 - 20 is €28.91.

I hope this explains everything! If you have any further questions, feel free to ask me!!

Thanks in advance

Greetings, Gideon

P.S. Here is a code snippet:

[CodePen.io](https://codepen.io/SuperHydroMan/pen/bGpxXwB)

Comment: The range you're talking about is dependent on `$contentL` only or `($contentL * $weight)` on this combination?

Comment: I think ```$contentL``` only. I am not sure myself.

Comment: if it is only on `$contentL` then also, after price calculation, if we multiply by `$weight` , price will change.

Comment: For now if we think that this range is for `($contentL * $weight)` i have one solution in my mind

Comment: Oh ok, Thanks! Looking forward to it

Comment: Did you get it working?

Comment: No, thanks anyways! I figured something out with other employees at this company.

Comment: If you get an answer, you can post by yourself, so in future anybody can reference to that

Comment: I can't really. We made it work with a custom WordPress Plugin which is NOT open source.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

// Define this `X` to which you want to increase price.
define('INCREASE_BY', 1);

// Update your last line of code with it.
$total = (DEFAULT_PRICE + ((ceil($contentL / 10) - 1) * INCREASE_BY)) * $weight;
echo $total;
```

Comment: Ok, let me try this!

Comment: This is not working as I tried to explain to you. Maybe this link will help??

https://www.tnt.com/express/nl_nl/site/get-quote.html

It's something like the form you see there. When the content reaches a specific amount the price scales up. So when I have like 12 liters of content for my delivery. Then its like €47,- , and when I have 18 liters of content then it will stay the same price.

BUT on the moment I go over the 20 liter mark, it gets a higer price (e.g €49,-)

Comment: i can't see, it is asking for login.

Comment: but the main thing what I've shared with you is how to make a constant for a range. If you know what to do, you can use this logic.

Comment: Oh ok, I'll try something! Thanks anyway for your time :)

Comment: If you don't have that `weight` variable, we can have the answer but using this variable if you still want a constant price that is not possible. Only possible solution is what i gave it to you.

Comment: There might be something small that you're missing here. One more thing can you explain why you are multiplying with weight when price is not dependent on it?

Comment: Well I need to have weight, and the content in liters to impact the price. How else do I wanna do this? If the package is heavier, its more expensive. So does the price increase when the package is larger.

Comment: can you get 2 or 3 sample inputs from that site and corresponding total value. Along with deafult value and to be increased price.

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: try the updated answer, and let's so whether it works or not

Comment: https://prnt.sc/ujf1r2
https://prnt.sc/ujf2p3

As you can see with these first 2 screenshots. The length, width and height are much higher values then before. but the price is the same.

https://prnt.sc/ujf2cr

This last screenshots shows you what happens with a larger box, but with the same weight.

Comment: and just to clarify, you need to update the `INCREASE_BY` whatever you want. `1` is for sample purpose.

Answer (score 0):

You probably should have price per weight and price for additional 10L seperatly and not multiply weight and liters

```
$total = DEFAULT_PRICE + (floor($contentL / 10) * $price10L) + ($weight * $price1kg);
```

Comment: I get the idea you're trying to make. Although This is not what I am looking for! I need something that only adds money when the the inputs go over 10 liters after the calculation

So (e.g. Everything with a output between 0 - 10 liters is €43,- and everything between 10 - 20 liters is like €48,-) and so on and on..